# Read 3 of every 4 bytes from file into bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, file, micropython

I'm new to python. I'm currently reading the contents of a file into a bytearray like so:

```
self.palette = bytearray(fp.read(paletteSize*4))
```

Instead of reading all the data, I need to do something like:

```
palette[0] = fp.read(1)
palette[1] = fp.read(1)
palette[2] = fp.read(1)
fp.read(1) #throw a byte away
palette[3] = fp.read(1)
# etc thru paletteSize * 4 bytes, resulting in a size * 3 array
```

Basically, I need to throw away every 4th byte and pack the remaining bytes into an array that is 3/4th the size.

What is the best way to do this that is both best performing and cleanest in code? I know I could do this manually like above with a for loop on a range, but that seems really ugly and involving a lot of memory copies in python rather in native C code.

The reason I ask: this is micropython and the files can be somewhat large (4+ KB), so saving 25% is significant.

Spoiler alert: I am reading the palette part of a bitmap file, which is encoded as four byte tuples of blue, green, red, 0x00 - the 4th byte of every palette entry being useless data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the palette size, you can preallocate memory for it to save a bit of overhead from extending the bytearray while you add data to it. Use a loop to read 3 bytes at a time and perform seek to skip 1 byte:

```
palette = bytearray(paletteSize * 3)
for i in range(paletteSize):
    palette[i * 3: (i + 1) * 3] = fp.read(3)
    fp.seek(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

So today I learned about slice assignment in Python, which was the missing magic. thank you @blhsing  :)

I ended up with this version, which avoids some math in the loop slice assignment:

```
self.palette = bytearray(paletteSize * 3)
   for i in range(0, paletteSize*3, 3):
      self.palette[i : (i + 3)] = fp.read(3)
      fp.seek(1, 1)
```

Added as an answer instead of a comment because stackoverflow comment formatting sucks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `struct` module.

```
s = struct.Struct("BBB")
b = bytearray()
for i in range(paletteSize)
    b.extend(s.unpack_from(f.read(4)))  # b.extend(f.read(4)[:3]) would also work
```

You may even be able to simplify this to

```
s = struct.Struct("BBBx" * paletteSize)
b = bytearray(s.unpack(f.read(paletteSize*4)))
```

although I haven't tested this; I've never used a format string as potentially large as this, but in theory it should work.

Comment: I'm not inclined to complexificate the code for such a simple task, but moreover, I won't have the struct module available in the micropython build I'm using, so this is a non-starter.

Comment: I was wondering if the full standard library was available for micropython. Oh, well.

Comment: It is! But I stripped it out of my build because it saves about 2kb of memory